# Typescript Reduce returning wrong Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I'm trying to use reduce to sum my SQL response in two categories, **income** and **outcome**, but I'm getting the "currentValue" (transaction) type as my return instead of the accumulator (BalanceDTO), I'm returning only the accumulator, how I'm getting the transaction type as my return type?

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, I am completely stuck for the last two hours.

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';

import Transaction from '../models/Transaction';

interface BalanceDTO {
  income: number;
  outcome: number;
}

class GetBalanceService {
  public async execute(): Promise<BalanceDTO> {
    const transactionRepository = getRepository(Transaction);

    const transactions = await transactionRepository.find();

    const balance = transactions.reduce(
      (accumulator: BalanceDTO, transaction): BalanceDTO => {
        accumulator[transaction.type] += transaction.value;
        return accumulator; //// HERE -- How it is returning the transactions type? ////
      },
    );

    return balance;
  }
}

export default GetBalanceService;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missing define initial value and type of initial value. Type of initial value will define return type of the `reduce` function.

I suggest define initial value as a BalanceDTO and start values is zero

```
const balance = transactions.reduce((accumulator, transaction) => {
  accumulator[transaction.type] += transaction.value;
  return accumulator;
}, {
    income: 0,
    outcome: 0,
} as BalanceDTO); // initialValue as a BalanceDTO
```

Now, `balance` is a BalanceDTO

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked flawlessly. Why in some cases (every other case I  had before this one) worked fine without declaring the initial statement (like the first example in the mozilla documentation) ?

Comment: @VictorThadeu "If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as currentValue." - document. It will be fine in some case, but I think you need put init value to make every clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an initial value for `accumulator` as the second argument of `recude` function:

```
const balance = transactions.reduce(
      (accumulator: BalanceDTO, transaction): BalanceDTO => {
        accumulator[transaction.type] += transaction.value;
        return accumulator; //// HERE -- How it is returning the transactions type? ////
      },
      {
          income: 0,
          outcome: 0
      }
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked flawlessly. Why in some cases (every other case I  had before this one) worked fine without declaring the initial statement (like the first example in the mozilla documentation) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
    const balance = transactions.reduce(
      (accumulator: BalanceDTO, transaction): BalanceDTO => {
        accumulator[transaction.type] += transaction.value;
        return accumulator;
      },{income: 0, outcome: 0} //you'd better set the initial value
    );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked flawlessly. Why in some cases (every other case I  had before this one) worked fine without declaring the initial statement (like the first example in the mozilla documentation) ?